# Space between elements in sub-menu

Tags: html, css, submenu

I'm making web site and I have a problem with my sub menu.
There is space between `<li>` elements in sub menu. Here is a photo from my web.
[image]

and when I try to click on Nutrition the sub-menu disappears.

Here is my code:

```css
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;
    left: -140px;
    background-color: #372412;
}

ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    background:#5f3e1b;
    color: #372412;
    height:30px;
}

ul#menu li ul.sub-menu a{
    background-color:#5f3e1b ;
    color: white;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #4A3903;
}
```

the code is a mess because I try everything to fix the problem but I can't.

Comment: There's more to it than what you've posted. Best to post a test page.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be useful here.